# Вывести текст нужного цвета

Tags: color, android, java

Здравствуйте! У меня есть вот такая модель:

```
public class TagModel extends EntityModel {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String color;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы вывести имя модели в переопределенном методе toString цветным?

Какая-нибудь альтернатива такой конструкции:

```
   return "<font color='" + color + "'>" + name + "</font>";
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так ты же и так его цветным выводишь  в textview можно выводить  html 
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));